# How to include another related object to query using Entity Framework and show it in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, windows-forms-designer

I do not know how to formulate this question correctly but I am coding a sales system and my issue is very simple but I am not well experienced using WindowsForm's ***DataGridView***. I want to show the total price of each sale in ***DataGridView*** but for getting the total price I need to make a sum of each product inside the related table.

These are my sales tables:

[image]

I am trying to get the total price of each sale making a sum with ***PrecioTotal***.

This is my code:

```
    public IList<Factura> GetListVentas()
    {
       return _context.Facturas
            .OrderByDescending(a => a.FechaVenta)
            .ToList(); 

    }
```

My windows Forms code to show items in DataGridview:

```
  BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
        var ventas = _facturasRepository.GetListVentas();
        source.DataSource = ventas;
        Listaventas.DataSource = typeof(List<>); 
        Listaventas.DataSource = source;
```

[image]

What I have tried:

```
        public IList<Factura> GetListVentas()
    {
       return _context.Facturas
            .Include(a => a.DetalleFacturas.Sum(b => b.PrecioTotal))
            .OrderByDescending(a => a.FechaVenta)
            .ToList(); 
    }
```

But I get this error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.

Comment: You need to create a dto object which will have Factura properties and Total amount. Then you select in your query. Something like return _context.Facturas.Include(a=>a.DetalleFacyuras).OrderByDesending(..).Select(x=> new FacuraSummaryDto{Total= x.DetallaFacturas.sum(...),..});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class FacturaDto{
public decimal Total {get;set;}
...
}

        public IList<FacturaDto>GetListVentas()
{
   return _context.Facturas
        .Include(a => a.DetalleFacturas). OrderByDescending(a => a.FechaVenta).Select(x=> new FacturaDto{Total = x.DetalleFacturas.Sum(b => b.PrecioTotal), ...})
        .ToList(); 
}
```